Trying to wire 2 Kasa HS220 Smart Dimmers side by side for 2 different lights in double gang box
Trying to wire 2 Kasa HS220 Smart Dimmers side by side for 2 different lights in double gang box. I wired it up and only one will power up. This is in a daisy chain configuration.

Without knowing more, there is not much we can tell.  Pictures will help.

We need a lot more information. Please [edit] to include labeled photos and/or diagrams of the wiring.

i remember when old folks criticized the tv remote control back in the day and didn't understand why.  Now we are to the point of not turning lights on and off via conventional switch, I think i get it now.

@ron   My parents had a voice controlled remote in the 60s.  If the remote did not work, a kick in the bottom usually fixed it.

By "daisy chain," do you mean the two dimmers are in series? If so, that is not how they should be connected. If you mean that the hot wire of one is connected to the hot wire of the line, then the other dimmer's hot wire should be connected, too.
